Is it easier to exit a box to the right of a box in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ if I remove some edges to the left?
Suppose that I am given the graph $G = (V,E)$ where
$V = \{ 1, 2, \dots 2N+1 \} \times \{ 1, 2, \dots 2N+1 \} $
and there is an edge between two vertices $(n,m)$ and $(n',m')$ if and only if
$\vert n-n'\vert + \vert m-m'\vert = 1$.
Suppose that we remove some arbitrary edges between vertices $(n,m)$ and $(n',m')$ with $n, n' \leq N$.
Now, on the remaining graph, consider Bernoulli edge percolation with parameter $p \in [0,1]$. That is that we delete each of the remaining edges with probability $1-p$. Prove or disprove that, no matter what edges I deleted in the beginning, then the probability that there is a path from $(N+1,N+1)$ to a vertex of the form $(2N+1, m)$ for $m \in  \{ 1, 2, \dots 2N+1 \}$ is larger or equal than the probability that there is a path to a vertex of the form $(1, m)$ for $m \in  \{ 1, 2, \dots 2N+1 \}$.
See here for a related counterexample: Are there more paths exiting a box in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ to the right if I remove some edges to the left.

Nice problem, so $G$ is just like a lattice on a square of sides $2N + 1$ if i understand correctly? There is an edge from $v$ to $w$ iff $w$ lies immediately to the top/left/right/bottom of $v$.

What does it mean to remove arbitrary edges between two vertices?

It means that you delete the edges from the beginning before sampling additional edges to remove.

Can it be thought of in terms of some effective probability of open edges  ($p_e$) on the left side which is less than $p$?

@AlapanDas: No, instead I ask if you can carefully remove some edges on the left so that the probability of getting a path to the left side increases.

If the arbitrary edges removed are between $(1, m_i)$ and $(1, m_i + 1)$ then they are irrelevant to the escape paths sought, so by symmetry this should be a counterexample.

Fair point,  I mean larger or equal. I edited.
